# Access variable set in batch from C# application

Tags: c#, batch-file, variables

I have a batch file `setEnv.bat`.

```
@echo off
set input=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
SET MY_VAR=%input%
```

I want to run this batch file from C# application and want to access the newly set value of `MY_VAR` from c# application.

C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName= "D:\\Check\\SetJavaHome.bat";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = 
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
proc.Start();
```

string myVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_VAR");

Can someone help me in getting this working as expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can access the variable only if it's written in the registry with `SETX` or if the program called from the batch file.

Comment: I am calling the batch file from C# program.

Comment: You could read the file as text, and just use regex to parse the file and get the value :p

Comment: @npocmaka I don't think `SETX` will work: it sets the _master_ environment, so _new_ processes/shells will see the new value, but the (already running) C# program won't see any changes.

Comment: @Ashley You can't do it this way. The environment changed by the batch file will only be visible within the batch file and anything it calls -- it will never affect the C# process that called it. The _point_ of using environment variables _inside_ a program is that they are set _outside_ the program before it is started. Either have a batch file that `call`s your existing batch file and then launches the C# program _or_ use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() inside your C# program (either reading the value from a file or configuration setting or parsing the existing batch file as Derek says

Answer (score 3):

Check out this answer with the sample code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51189308/9630273

Getting the Environment variables directly from another process is not possible, but a simple workaround can be like:

Create a dummy bat file (env.bat) that will execute the required bat and echo the environment variable.
Get the output of this env.bat inside the process execution of C#.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you want to do this is a bit vague but if your only option is to run that batchfile from a call to `Process.Start` then the following trickery will let you promote the environment vars from the batch file to your own process.

This is the batch file I use:

> ```
> set test1=fu
> set test2=bar
> ```

The followng code opens a standard Command Prompt and then uses the [`StandardInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) to send commands to the command prompt and receive the results with [OutputDataReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx). I basically caputure the output of the `SET` command and the parse over its result. For each line that contains an environment var and value I call [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVaruable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the environment in our own process.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
bool capture = false;

var proc = new Process();
// we run cms on our own
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
// we want to capture and control output and input
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

// get all output from the commandline
proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => { if (capture) sb.AppendLine(e.Data); };

// start
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine(); // will start raising the OutputDataReceived

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd \tmp"); // where is the cmd file
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // give it a second
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"setenv.cmd"); // run the cmd file
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // give it a second

capture = true; // what comes next is of our interest
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"set"); // this will list all environmentvars for that process
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // give it a second
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit"); // done
proc.WaitForExit();

// parse our result, line by line
var sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
string line = sr.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    var firstEquals = line.IndexOf('=');
    if (firstEquals > -1)
    {
        // until the first = will be the name
        var envname = line.Substring(0, firstEquals);
        // rest is the value
        var envvalue = line.Substring(firstEquals+1);
        // capture what is of interest
        if (envname.StartsWith("test"))
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envname, envvalue);
        }
    }
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test2")); // will print > bar
```

This will bring the environment variables that are set by a command file into your process.

Do note you can achieve the same by creating a command file that first calls your batchfile and then start your program:

```
rem set all environment vars
setenv.cmd 
rem call our actual program
rem the environment vars are inherited from this process
ConsoleApplication.exe
```

The latter is easier and works out of the box, no brittle parsing code needed.