# Not able to access environment variable in batch file from C# application

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

i have one batch file and in that i am trying to access environment variable. its able to get that variable if i just click it and run but when i run it from the C# code its not able to accees the  environment variable and and shows blank.

for example in the batch say its written - echo %ENV_VAR_NAMe%
this will work if i just click the batch. but from c# code it shows blank.
C# code is given below. please help

```
      try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = 
            Path.GetDirectoryName(exe);
            myProcess.Start();  
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
            myProcess.Close();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I do not see where you access the environment in your code

Comment: Is your C# code running as your user, or is it running as part of some scheduled task as a different user? That could explain the difference.

Comment: Its in the batch file "exe" variable name in the code would be path of the batch file like D:\\Test\\BatchFileName.bat and echo %ENV_VAR_NAMe% is written in the batch file.

Comment: i would say its running as a user but while clicking on the batch its able to access the env. variable and not from the code

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (including C# code and the batch file). Also, did you **just** add the environment variable? If so, please reboot your machine and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Run programs and get environment variables after they run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783407/c-sharp-run-programs-and-get-environment-variables-after-they-run)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` ?

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
public class Example 
{ 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        // Change the directory to %WINDIR%
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"); 
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(".");
        Console.WriteLine("Directory Info: " + info.FullName); 
    } 
} 

// The example displays output like the following: // Directory Info: C:\windows
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your first question is pretty unclear actually. What does it change for you to know how it works?

Comment: thanks @Arnaud F. for help. the cmd code example i gave is just one small part. i need it in the batch itself. cant change it. thats why i am not trying to access env. variable using C# code

Comment: i can add extra code into the batch file but i cant remove parts of the batch that is the condition here and i am trying to execute that batch using c# code.